# Posting guidance and down voting

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I would like some guidance as to who downvotes a question and why. I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095719/blobs-or-something-else) regarding the use of Azure Blobs. It states the problem and how I was planning to solve it.

The question was asking advice on what would be best practice as I am unsure if my approach is the best way. The intention being that the post may foster some discussion on the topic.

I have been downvoted which in my experience means users are less likely to read or respond to the post.

I think the downvote is harsh and in this case a little unfair unless I am missing the point of this site.

Comment: Your question also has two Close Votes for being *primarily opinion-based*. Possibly the downvote came from one of these people.

Comment: You question says *I am not asking for how it's done just researching what would be best practice for implementing such a solution.* That's arguably worse than asking how it's done, and makes your question primarily opinion-based. You're also asking for alternatives, which taints your question as being about recommending something. This accumulation of issues might very well have directed one user to the downvote arrow.

Comment: The irony is that I stated I wasn't looking for a "How To' because the last time I did this for something I had no idea about I got downvoted assuming because they felt I had not tried myself and was being lazy. In this case I had looked into it and figured out a solution but wasn't sure if it was the best way to go so thought stack overflow would be a reasonable place to seek advice.

Comment: Also, "best paractices" is a red flag for "Primarily opinion-based": Read [this epic piece on why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354).

Comment: Your question is rather broad, asks for "best practices" which is always a red flag (do you think people recommend "worst practices" around here?), asks for "any alternatives" to blobs (external resource request, or worse, googling request) and is overall just too unspecific. SO is for specific questions, not something open-ended like "how to design my whole storage system".

Comment: Fair enough I think I am slowing figuring out how to conduct myself on this site. It's a shame cos for some reason I am taking some pride in my reputation and for some reason take it personally when someone knocks it down without a chance to reword or remove. Ah well! Thanks for taking the time to explain   my folly :-)

Comment: Not sure why this meta q is getting downvoted. It's not a rant or anything like that, OP is just looking for some guidance (which is exactly what Meta is for).

Comment: @Yannis it's in the details. The last sentence should have asked for possible reasons of the downvote instead of saying "the downvote is harsh and unfair". (I personally didn't vote here.)

Comment: @Stijn The question is in the first sentence followed by some context. Yannis, Deduplicator, l4mpi, Frederic and yourself have all helped clarify what I did wrong so all good. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question is not a rant, it's a user asking for guidance. I don't think this should be downvoted. Have my +1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a world of difference between

> Hey what are my options for X and what's the difference between them tell me the best practices please

and

> I'm considering building X and using Y. I have to decide between A and B and I'm not sure of the tradeoffs. I believe that A is blah, blah, and blah, but blah. In contrast B has blahier blahs, but I'm not sure if that's helpful in my circumstances and I can't understand the pricing model to figure out what I'll be paying extra for that. How large does your foo need to be to see a benefit from choosing B? What is the break-even point between paying by the month for A and by the transaction for B?

The well written "help me decide which is better" question **might** be on topic. It **might** belong better on Programmers (where whiteboardy architecty questions are on topic.) But no matter which site you ask it on, it's clearly better-written (with more research) and less likely to be downvoted. More importantly, it will get you better answers, because folks who just Google the X for you and paste in the blah blah blah sentences weren't really helping you anyway, and this heads them off at the pass.

To answer your asked question here, I'm guessing your downvotes were for being more like the first example than the second. To respond here to your comment there, closing your SO question will not get you your points back, only deleting will, and you don't want to delete it. Instead, edit it to make it better, and increase your chances of getting not only rep, but more importantly your answers.

Comment: [How can Stack Overflow help developers evaluate technologies?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145813/165773) - an epic answer (incidentally, from Programmers moderator)

Comment: @gnat Great article. I suppose this is what separates this website from the rest so while feeling a little harsh sometime maybe for the good of the site. The only suggestion is maybe a better workflow for the OP to challenge the downvote directly (to the downvote) in order to edit or delete the question.